# Python output window disappears immediately in eclipse after run

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I use eclipse IDE and pydev plugins for python development. In eclipse when I run the following code snippet the program output window appears and disappears immediately. How to solve this when using **ecliple** (not using by terminal or command prompt)?

```html
import turtle 
wn = turtle.Screen() 
alex = turtle.Turtle() 

alex.forward(50) 
alex.left(90) 
alex.forward(30) 

wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you  get an error, it has nothing to do with eclipse:

```
AttributeError: '_Screen' object has no attribute 'mainloop'
```

If you want a continuous loop use a while loop or a for loop:

```
import turtle
while True:
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    alex = turtle.Turtle()

    alex.forward(50)
    alex.left(90)
    alex.forward(30)
```

If you want to just see the keep the screen up use exitonclick()

```
wn.exitonclick()
```

[the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/turtle.html#methods-specific-to-screen-not-inherited-from-turtlescreen)

Comment: Very cool; That's it what I just wanted. Thanks a lot Mr.Padraic Cunningham.